# Where best to store a version number in Word document?

Tags: vsto, versioning, cpu-word

I have a VSTO Add-In that fills a specific Word template document with data from a third party software. The trick here is that some changes in the script are connected to changes in the document. What I want to do now is to **manually** store some kind of version number in the document information so I can check in the script if the version of the document fits the version of the script.

I already took a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document) but there are too many possibilities and I don't just want to pick any random object. I need to store it somewhere where it doesn't get changed.
Where would you recommend to store such a value?

edit: the version number has to be set manually because not every change of the document affects the script.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.variables - can be displayed in a document by using a `DocVariable` field but can only be added, or the value changed, by using code.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt That seems to be very useful, thank you! If you write that as an answer I can mark and upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

1. [Document property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.customdocumentproperties) - can be displayed in a document by using a `DocProperty` field but can be viewed and easily changed by the user.
2. [Document variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.variables) - an old school method but still valid. Can be displayed in a document by using a `DocVariable` field but can only be added, or the value changed, by using code.
3. [Custom XML Part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.customxmlparts) - can be displayed in a document by mapping to a content control which can allow the value to be changed by the user. If not mapped can only be changed using code, but not as simply as a document variable.

Comment: Option 2 is perfect for me. Thanks a lot